# Only allow to register users to the admin in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my scenario, the users can not register, there will be an admin, and that admin will create the users with a default password they can change later.

I am reviewing the pluralsight videos and according to those I should put the [Authorize] tag in the action method.

I did the following, but once I did this, I cant see anything on http://localhost/Account/Register, neither as a logged in user.

1. The role admin already exists.
2. The logged in user is also associated to that role in the UserInRoles table.

If I remove the [Authorize] attribute, then I can access the register page.

```
// GET: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The logon partial is:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account") ]
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Account") ]
    [ @Html.ActionLink("Position", "Position", "Position") ]
    [ @Html.ActionLink("User Position", "Position", "UserPositionPosition") ]
    </text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}








 EDIT: I better attached the full account controller for better understanding

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using HRRazorForms.Models;

namespace HRRazorForms.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        //
        // GET: /Account/LogOn

        public ActionResult LogOn()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOn

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/LogOff

        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]       
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles="admin")]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
                Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

                if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ChangePassword

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ChangePassword

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
                // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                try
                {
                    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
                    changePasswordSucceeded = currentUser.ChangePassword(model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                }

                if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ChangePasswordSuccess");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ChangePasswordSuccess

        public ActionResult ChangePasswordSuccess()
        {
            return View();
        }

        #region Status Codes
        private static string ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
        {
            // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550 for
            // a full list of status codes.
            switch (createStatus)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                    return "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A user name for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                    return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                default:
                    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I removed the HttpPost attribute from the register that returns the view, its supposed to be a get.

Comment: are you sure you have removed the [HttpPost] attribute from the parameterless action? I hadn't noticed that one, but Hector Correa's comment showed it up.  You mustn't remove it from the Action with the model parameter, only the parameterless one as this is a Get method.

Comment: yes I did, and I also added a screenshot with the tables of the membership tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem with this is that rolemanager was set to false instead of true by default in the web.config.

Sorry for that, was easy to solve, but never thought it would be disabled.!

Comment: I am glad you figured it out and posted the solution!

Answer (score 1):

That should work.

I would say that you have done something else when trying different things.

EG:  Are you sure you don't have a different Authorize attribute on the controller?  For example:

```
[Authorize(Roles="ADifferentRole")]
```

Is the admin role spelled correctly (for example, sure its not administration instead of admin)?

Are you sure that you haven't registered, then not noticed that instead of being logged in as the admin, you are now logged in as the recently created user (see below, there is a bug of sorts in your code).

Sorry I can't be more help, but what you have shown should work.

### Bug:

Your HttpPost Action for Register has a fault in it for the kind of use you want to give it.  If you have another user creating the logins, then when that user registers someone successfully, your code is going to set the authentication cookie to that of the new user.

This is probably the cause of your problem.  The code that does this is:

```
if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

You need to replace that block with:

```
if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // or wherever you want to go...
            }
```

Comment: I pasted the entire account controller, this is actually weird, if I remove the HttpPost attribute, then it shows me the login page, if I keep the HttpPost attribute, then it shows me 404 Error Page not found. Even, when logged in, it still shows me the login page when I click on Register.

Comment: its like in an Infinite loop, I click register, and it redirects to login page, fine, then I login, and I click register again it shows me the login page again instead of the register page.  I also commented the line you said.

Comment: @Luis: you need to have a Register action **without** the HttpPost attribute in order to allow a user to login. When users first visit the page they'll come with a HTTP GET and you don't have a method to support this.

Comment: I already removed it, and then I can see the login page when user clicks on register, but even then after loging in, it keeps showing me the login page instead of the register page., any idea?

Comment: @Luis:  that is definitely because the user you login in as does not have the admin role.  Check to see that "admin" is the correct name, and that the user you are logging in as has the admin role.  If it still doesn't work, double check.

Comment: @Luis: Does it work if you use a plain [Authorize] attribute in your Register action (i.e. without a role)?

Comment: @Luis: Another thing. I believe the reason you are being sent to the login page over and over is because ASP.NET is detecting (for whatever reason) that you are not authenticated.

Comment: @awrigley please see the screenshot there is the proof the user is associated with the  role.

Comment: @HectorCorrea I removed the role from the register parameterless action, and voila it works.!! Am I missing something in the database? please see the screenshot.

Comment: @Luis: I suspect the issue is with the Application settings. Did you change the applicationName value in the web.config (under the membership section)? I believe there is an aspnet_Applications table that identifies the application. It is possible that that's where the missing link is.

Comment: I just checked and the application name in the table is "/", in the web.config it also has that setting. <membership>
      <providers>

        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4200/discussion-between-luis-and-hector-correa)

Comment: @Luis: Sorry, if it wasn't that then I am out of ideas.

Comment: @HectorCorrea the strange this is that it works with  [Authorize(Users="levalencia")] but not with the roles.